# Query for latest record date for each product and part type (Include part type is null)

Tags: sql, db2

My database looks like this
Table name : Process_Result

```
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'' Product_No '' Part_Type '' INPUT_DATE '' PROCESS_CD ''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'' 111111     ''           '' 01/05/2021 '' First      ''
'' 111111     ''     M     '' 10/05/2021 '' Five       ''
'' 111111     ''     M     '' 01/05/2021 '' Four       ''
'' 111111     ''     N     '' 03/05/2021 '' First      ''
'' 222222     ''           '' 02/05/2021 '' Second     ''
'' 222222     ''           '' 05/05/2021 '' Third      ''
'' 222222     ''     N     '' 10/05/2021 '' First      ''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
```

Select product and part type together and select only max date row

The result I want:

```
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'' Product_No '' Part_Type '' INPUT_DATE '' PROCESS_CD ''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'' 111111     ''           '' 01/05/2021 '' First      ''
'' 111111     ''     M     '' 10/05/2021 '' Five       ''
'' 111111     ''     N     '' 03/05/2021 '' First      ''
'' 222222     ''           '' 05/05/2021 '' Third      ''
'' 222222     ''     N     '' 10/05/2021 '' First      ''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
```

Now my query look like this:

```
SELECT product_no,
       part_type,
       input_time,
       process_cd
FROM   process_result AS A
WHERE  A.input_time = (SELECT Max(input_time)
                       FROM   process_result AS B
                       WHERE  A.product_no = B.product_no
                              AND A.part_type = B.part_type)
```

It's don't show the null data of A table equal null data of B table
I already search on google and I still don't understand it.
Now the result is this :

```
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'' Product_No '' Part_Type '' INPUT_DATE '' PROCESS_CD ''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'' 111111     ''     M     '' 10/05/2021 '' Five       ''
'' 111111     ''     N     '' 03/05/2021 '' First      ''
'' 222222     ''     N     '' 10/05/2021 '' First      ''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
```

Comment: Have you got Scripts for tables and insert statements ?

Comment: Only sql question bro sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Product_No and Part_Type seem like a natural grouping here, try using row_number()...

```sql
select Product_No, Part_Type, Input_Date, Process_CD
from (
  select Product_No, Part_Type, Input_Date, Process_CD,
    rn = row_number() over (partition by product_no, part_type order by Input_Date desc)
  from dbo.Process_Result
) src
where rn=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` in sql means "undefined" or "unknown". Nothing is equal to an unknown value, the result is also unknown. So there will be no match with a `NULL` value in a join. But you could replace the `NULL` with an empty string with `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT product_no,
       part_type,
       INPUT_DATE AS input_time,
       process_cd
FROM   process_result AS A
WHERE  A.INPUT_DATE = (SELECT Max(INPUT_DATE)
                       FROM   process_result AS B
                       WHERE  A.product_no = B.product_no
                              AND COALESCE(A.part_type,'') = COALESCE(B.part_type,''))
```

Here's a sql-fiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/75bf07/5

But i would also prefer the [`ROW_NUMBER` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67531984/284240) in sql-server.

(note that you used `INPUT_DATE` in your data but `input_time` in your sql)

Comment: My database is DB2. I think it don't have COALESCE. Do you have another way ?

Comment: @ThanakornThongsomboon: afaik all databases know [`COALESCE`](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000780.html). Also, if it's DB2 why you tag SQL-Server which is the microsoft rdbms?

Comment: @ThanakornThongsomboon, if you are using DB2, then tag your question with DB2 and remove the Microsoft SQL Server tag (sql-server). That said, I expect DB2 would support the standard SQL `COALESCE` function.

Comment: @DanGuzman Sorry bro. This is my first post I don't know it. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: It's awesome bro. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ThanakornThongsomboon: glad it helped. You can accept an answer if your question is solved

Answer (score 0):

It is simple:  Almost any comparison between `NULL` values returns `NULL`.  A `WHERE` clause keeps rows where the condition evaluates to `TRUE`, so `NULL` values are filtered out.

The SQL Standard supports a `NULL`-safe comparison, so `NULL IS NOT DISTINCT FROM NULL` returns `TRUE`.  However, `NULL = NULL` returns `NULL`.  You can write this using the `IS DISTINCT FROM` predicate:

```
SELECT pr.product_no, pr.part_type, pr.input_time, pr.process_cd
FROM process_result pr
WHERE pr.input_time = (SELECT MAX(pr2.input_time)
                       FROM process_result pr2
                       WHERE pr2.product_no = pr.product_no AND
                             pr2.part_type IS NOT DISTINCT FROM pr.part_type
                      );
```

Or without:

```
SELECT pr.product_no, pr.part_type, pr.input_time, pr.process_cd
FROM process_result pr
WHERE pr.input_time = (SELECT MAX(pr2.input_time)
                       FROM process_result pr2
                       WHERE pr2.product_no = pr.product_no AND
                             (pr2.part_type = pr.part_type OR pr2.part_type IS NULL and pr.part_type IS NULL)
                      );
```

Note that this uses an *explicit* comparison.  It does not replace `NULL` with another value -- which can get confused with an existing value in another row.

That said, AlwaysLearning's approach using `ROW_NUMBER()` is probably a better way to formulate your query.

Comment: Db2 does support [DISTINCT predicate](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=predicates-distinct-predicate).